# Which monk monastic tradition in the PHB gives the best usage of Wisdom for damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

I am currently playing a monk who has a +4 Wisdom  modifier.  I'm now 2nd level and next level I will need to choose a monastic tradition.
However, I don't want to waste my +4 Wisdom bonus.

#### Which monastic tradition offers the best usage of Wisdom for damage?

We're only using the Player's Handbook.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "best"? Are you looking to maximize damage, or something else?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "waste" as well. You get Unamoured Defensee and Ki Points regardless of what tradition you take.

Comment: Yes I want to know about damage and Im only including players handbook but if you know more school Can you tell me??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Monastic tradition features use Wisdom only to calculate saving throw DC-s.

The Way of Shadow practically does not use it at all, only as the DC against *minor illusion*.

The Way of the Open Hand uses it for

- All 3 options of the Open Hand Technique
- Save for *sanctuary* from Tranquility
- Save versus the effects of Quivering Palm

All play a major role in the subclass.

The Way of the Four Elements uses Wisdom as a save DC against all spells and effects that need one (and 12 out of 17 options do).

While none of the subclasses "wastes" a high Wisdom score, Open Hand and Four Elements depend on it rather heavily, while Shadow pretty much ignores it. Note however, the features from the Monk base class also use Wisdom.